# sqoop failed to overwrite

Tags: azure-sql-database, sqoop, azure-blob-storage

Im using the below command for importing data from sqlserver to Azure blob storage

```
sqoop import -Dorg.apache.sqoop.splitter.allow_text_splitter=true --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://server-IP;database=database_name;username=user;password=password"
--username test --password "password" --query "select top 5 * from employ where \$CONDITIONS" --delete-target-dir --target-dir 'wasb://sample@workingclusterblob.blob.core.windows.net/source/employ'
-m 1
```

getting below error

```
18/01/30 03:35:45 INFO tool.ImportTool: Destination directory wasb://sample@workingclusterblob.blob.core.windows.net/source/employ is not present, hence not deleting.
18/01/30 03:35:45 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning query import.
18/01/30 03:35:46 INFO client.AHSProxy: Connecting to Application History server at headnodehost/10.0.0.19:10200
18/01/30 03:35:46 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory wasb://sample@workingclusterblob.blob.core.windows.net/source/employ already exists
```

Logs statement are confusing which tells both as not present for deleting and present while writing.

Answer (score 0):

From Apache Sqoop user guide:

> By default, imports go to a new target location. If the destination
>   directory already exists in HDFS, Sqoop will refuse to import and
>   overwrite that directory’s contents. If you use the --append argument,
>   Sqoop will import data to a temporary directory and then rename the
>   files into the normal target directory in a manner that does not
>   conflict with existing filenames in that directory.

I'm not in the Azure environment to reproduce and validate the solution, But Try adding the `--append` to your sqoop import and let me know.

```
sqoop import -Dorg.apache.sqoop.splitter.allow_text_splitter=true --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://server-IP;database=database_name;username=user;password=password"
--username test --password "password" --query "select top 5 * from employ where \$CONDITIONS" --delete-target-dir --append --target-dir 'wasb://sample@workingclusterblob.blob.core.windows.net/source/employ'
-m 1
```